# margin is not set for a section tag

Tags: css, html

i am trying to set the margin-top for a section tag of my page. but when i set margin top for a particular section tag then the header tag also comes down with that. Please tell me the correct way to set the margin-top for a section tag here is my css. Id container is id of a section tag on which i am trying to set margin

```
body{
 background-color:#F7F7F7;
}

#logo
{
background-image:url('../Images/LogoEB.jpg');
background-repeat:no-repeat;
width:128px;
height:150px;
}
 #menu
{
float:left;
width:92%
}
nav ul
{
float:right;
list-style:none;
padding:0;
margin-right:10%;

}
nav li
{
float:left;
margin:0 1em;
color:#605C5D;
font-size:20px;


}
#login
{
float:right;
margin-right:4%;
width:auto;
margin-top:-4%;
}

#container
{

    position: relative;
 margin-top:50px;

background-color:#7F00FF;

}
```

my html

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<title>Online Education</title>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name ="viewport" content="width=device-width,intial-scale=1.0"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="Css/reset.css" type="text/css" media="screen"/>
<link rel="stylesheet"  href="Css/style.css" type="text/css" media="screen"/>
<script src="Js/modernizr.js"></script>
<script src="Js/respond.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div>
<header>
<div id="menu">
<h1>

<div id="logo">

</div>

<nav>
<ul>
<li>
HOW IT WORKS
</li>
<li>
COURSES
</li>
<li>
SCHOOLS
</li>
<li>
REGISTER
</li>


</ul>
</nav>



</h1>
</div>
<div id="login">
<input type="button" value="login" id="loginbtn"/>
</div>
</header>
</div>
<div id="container">
<section  >
<div >

</div>
</section>
</div>
</body>
<html>
```

Comment: You need to post your HTML also

Comment: were s your html..? or else give your URL

Comment: please check i add html

Comment: This HTML markup doesn't look to be valid at all. What's that bunch of stuff within the `H1` tag?

Comment: @MelanciaUK please tell me what i have to do?

Comment: You should make use of the [w3c markup validator](http://validator.w3.org)

Comment: Also, why do you have so many divs? I mean the ones around your section and header; they serve no purpose. And don't call them tags; they're elements.

Comment: @MrLister okk then what i have to use in place of div sir?

Comment: @AzadChouhan Nothing! You don't need to wrap headers or sections in divs. Just leave them out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add this css for your container...remove other css of your container just paste it

```
background-color: #7F00FF;
float: left;
margin-top: 50px;
position: relative;
```

Comment: thanks its working now but can u please explain me why its happen?